# Resolution preserving Fully Convolutional Network

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am new to ML and Pytorch and I have the following problem:

I am looking for a Fully Convolutional Network architecture in Pytorch, so that the input would be an RGB image (HxWxC or 480x640x3) and the output would be a single channel image (HxW or 480x640). In other words, I am looking for a network that will preserve the resolution of the input (HxW), and will loose the channel dimension. All of the networks that I've came across (ResNet, Densenet, ...) end with a fully connected layer (without any upsampling or deconvolution). This is problematic for two reasons:

1. I am restricted with the choice of the input size (HxWxC).
2. It has nothing to do with the output that I expect to get (a single channel image HxW).

What am I missing? Why is there even a FC layer? Why is there no up-sampling, or  some deconvolution layers after feature extraction? Is there any build-in torchvision.model that might suit my requirements? Where can I find such pytorch architecture? As I said, I am new in this field so I don't really like the idea of building such a network from scratch.

Thanks.

Comment: check out the [`torchvision.segmentation.models`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#semantic-segmentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably came across the networks that are used in classification. So they end up with a pooling and a fully connected layer to produce a fixed number of categorical output.

Have a look at Unet
https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/

Note: the original unet implementation use a lot of tricks.
You can simply downsample and then upsample symmetrically to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Your kind of task belongs to dense classification tasks, e.g. segmentation. In those tasks, we use fully convolution nets (see [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) for the original paper). In the FCNs you don't have any fully-connected layers, because when applying fully-connected layers you lose spatial information which you need for the dense prediction. Also have a look at the [U-Net paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf). All state-of-the art architectures use some kind of encoder-decoder architecture extended for example with a pyramid pooling module.

There are some implementations in the pytorch model zoo [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#semantic-segmentation). Search also Github for pytorch implementations for other networks.